# Firebase and REST - query data by range with a unix timestamp

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data looks line this:

```
development-
    minute-
       USD-
          1479185820-
             {"foo":"bar","unix_ts":1479185820}
          1479186000-
             {"foo":"bar","unix_ts":1479186000}
```

I want to query range but it returns all if the results.  Also how to I do an order by?

```
curl 'https://dude-3fdc.firebaseio.com/development/minute/AUD_USD.json?auth=adfadf3M3d9Za&orderBy="development/minute/USD/unix_ts"&startAt=1479229020&endAt=1479229080'

{
  "error" : "Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"development/minute/USD/unix_ts\", for path \"/development/minute/USD\", to the rules"
```

And per the docs I guess I have to use an index.  Below is my default rules.  How would I do an index?  The documentation is rather terrible for rest based queries.

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "development":{
      "minute":{
        "USD":{
      ".indexOn": ["unix_ts"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or as its becoming clear firebase is not suited for time series data.  Hence back to mysql.

Comment: Ordering data is done by specifying an `orderBy` parameter. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-ordered-data

Comment: Firebase can certainly and easily handle time series data. You *really* need to take a look at the documentation and examples on the Firebase website. .startingAt and .endingAt will give you ranges and .orderyBy will order the data.

Comment: well the docs and how to index data is biased for non - time series data which forced me to dump firebase as a viable solotion

Comment: I think you need to move the ".indexOn" two levels up in the JSON hierarchy